# When server is down, it won't return error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a factory

```
  angular.module('app.services',[])
    .factory('myFactory', function($http){
      return {
        getData: function(){
          return {animal: 'dog'}
        },
        isUser: function() {
          var url='http://parleyvale.com/isUser/';
          var promise=$http.get(url).   
            success(function(data, status) {
              console.log(data);
              console.log(status);
              return data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status){
              console.log(data || "Request failed");
              console.log(status);
              var data = {message: "Server is down"}
              return data;
            });
          return promise;
        },    ...
```

that provides data for a controller

```
  angular.module('app.controllers',[])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function($scope, myFactory){
      $scope.factoryOutput=myFactory.getData();  
      $scope.isUser=myFactory.isUser().then(function(data){
        console.log(data.data.items);
        $scope.factoryOutput2=data.data.items
      });  ...
```

But if the server is down it returns nothing though the console gets

```
x GET http://parleyvale.com/isUser/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How can I structure my code so that it catches the error when the server is down? Here is http://jsbin.com/nebed/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing in your controller code is a second function argument to `then`, which handles the failure:

```
$scope.isUser=myFactory.isUser('tim').then(function(data){
    console.log(data.data.items);
    $scope.factoryOutput2=data.data.items
}, function(data){ $scope.factoryOutput2 = data });
```

[Clone of your JS Bin with updates](http://jsbin.com/koyijomi/1/edit)

Comment: That's sweet but promises are sweeter. When you write them they look clean. I'm switching over, I promise